# Firebase remote config - language conditions not working - android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am using firebase remote-config in my app. I have two parameters message1 and message2 as shown in image below. The language conditions can also be seen in the image (its for arabic and french).

[image]

User has option to select app language at beginning of app (separate activity) and this is the code I use to change language:

```
            Locale locale = new Locale("ar");//or "fr" if user selects french
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.locale = locale;
            getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

This is the code I use to fetch data from firebase:

```
mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(R.xml.remote_config_defaults);

long cacheExpiration = 0;
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)
        .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fetch Succeeded",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // After config data is successfully fetched, it must be activated before newly fetched
                    // values are returned.
                    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fetch Failed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                String welcomeMessage1 = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("message1");
                String welcomeMessage2 = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("message2");
            }
        });
```

Now the issue is that whenever I try to get the message1 and message2 from server it returns the default English text only and it will never return the corresponding arabic or french locale text. Why is this? Please help.

Comment: Could you try to call getString() after the activateFetched().
Also, could you show your conditions - how have you built the french locale condition? Thanks

Comment: i have tried calling getString() after activateFetched(). But still same issue persist. For parameter condition is set from Firebase console by clicking, add value for condition -> applies if-device language-"fr"

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? I am stuck on a similar issue.

Comment: anyone found this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The **[language condition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters?authuser=0)** checks for device language not for application language, so I think that you need to add a [user property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties?authuser=0) with the application language and compare with it

Answer (score 0):

[remote-config 19.1.3](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#remote-config_v19-1-3) fixed it.

> Fixed an issue where FirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch() would sometimes
>   report a misformatted language tag.

Try to upgrade firebase to [the latest version](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)